# Cut audio signal in specific Segments. (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to cut the audio signal in a specific segment in ms. I have tried the below code and it works okay but only for one segment. How can I cut the signal in multiple segments?

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('myAudioData.wav');
cutData = y((Fs * (1 - 1)) + 1 : Fs * (2 - 1), :);
plot(linspace(1, 2, length(cutData)), cutData);
```

**EDITED**

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('myAudioData.wav');
 nSamOr=length(y);
 zVec=7865657/10^9;
zVecE=zVec+0.050;
zVecS=zVec-0.050;
startTime = ((zVecS + (zVecE-zVecS))/(2 - 10));
EndTime = ((zVecS + (zVecE-zVecS))/(2 + 10));
cutData = y((Fs * (startTime)) + 1 : Fs * (EndTime ), :);
plot(linspace(1, 2, length(cutData)), cutData);
```

I am getting the below error:
Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in Test1 (line 9)
cutData = y((Fs * (startTime)) + 1 : Fs * (EndTime ), :);

Anyone who can help why I am getting this error?

Comment: You can insert the code that now extract a single segment in a `for` loop; depending on your needs, the start and end point of each segment can be set in an array before the loop or computed at each iteration, so they will be used to extrac the data in `cutData`

Comment: @il_raffa thanks very much for your reply. I have tried to do that and gives me an error "Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values."

Comment: You should post the code that generates the error so we can check it

Comment: @il_raffa I have updated the code but I have not included the for loop as I am getting this error and without the loop.